# In Django how I can create automatically a many to many entry based on a field found in two models

Tags: python, django, database-design, orm, many-to-many

I have the following models example:

```python
class TestSet(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Class(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    test_set_id = models.ForeignKey(TestSet)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Test(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    test_set_id = models.ForeignKey(TestSet)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class ClassTest(models.Model):
    class_id = models.ForeignKey(Class)
    test_id = models.ForeignKey(TestSet)
    memo = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.memo
```

What I want to do is when a new Class or Test is created, it should also create automatically a ClassTest entry if their test_set_id matches with the currenct entries on the database.

Example:

1. Lets say I already have three **Test** objects with test_set_id = 1
2. I create a new **Class** object with test_set_id = 1
3. After creating the new **Class** object, the program should also create 3 new entries in the **ClassTest** model connecting classes to tests based on the match of the test_set_id field.
4. It should work the same if a new **Test** object is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are two answers that comes in mind:

1. You can use [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/) to create a receiver that execute a specific command when a Class object is created. Something around the code below. Consider that the `instance` is basically the just created class and you can simply operate standard django query with that do get and create additional objects.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Class)
def create_test_sets(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ///do things///
```

2. On a second beat thought, I would ask what's the overall use-case your are trying to solve. I feel there is some redundancy here but I can't fully figure out where unless you help me gather the bigger picture.

Comment: I solved the problem with signals thanks. About the redundancy I feel that too. The use case would be: 1. an administrator makes some classes were he will specify a testset field and assign a teacher for each. 2. after that a test_creator will add some tests with that testset field specified for each. 3. if the testset from classes is the same as the added quizzes ones than a link should be made between those two. 4. next time a teacher login into his account he should be able to see all the quizzes available for his classes.